# Zend Services Not Starting After Reboot CentOS 7

Tags: zend-server, zend-server-installation

I am using VMWare Workstation Desktop to test new zendserver.
Install CentOS 7 minimum install.
CENTOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (core)

I have disabled SEinux. reboot.

Install ZendServer-8.5.2-update1

Everything works ok. I can reach http://192.168.1.37:10081/ZendServer/Dashboard/

but after reboot zend server don't responded.

If I manually start zend server - everything goes well.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received answer from zend server support:

The problem is caused by a bug in RHEL/CentOS 7.2 systemd (bug was already fixed but have not been shipped yet).

Meanwhile, you can use the following workaround (as root):

## rm -f /etc/init.d/zend-server

## cp -p /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh /etc/init.d/zend-server